# Altering text elements in multiple mxds?

Tags: arcpy, mxd, typeerror, element

I am trying to make changes to titles on multiple mxds instead of having to open 1 by 1 but keep getting an error.

```
import arcpy.mapping as mapping, os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"F:\Final Maps\New folder"): # GetPArameterAsTExt(0)
    for name in files:
        filename = os.path.join(root, name) 
        if ".mxd" in filename:
            mxd = mapping.MapDocument(filename)
            for map in mxd:
                for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(map, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
                    if elm.text == "TEST 90666":
                        elm.text = "9067"
```

This is the error that I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Please always provide errors as text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because the `arcpy.mapping.MapDocument` object does not support iteration. You would need to construct a list of map document files (which can be done with `os.walk()` or a list of `arcpy.mapping.MapDocument` objects and then iterate it.

So the line `for map in mxd:` should be removed.

```
import arcpy.mapping as mapping, os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"F:\Final Maps\New folder"): # GetParameterAsText(0)
    for name in files:
        filename = os.path.join(root, name) 
        if ".mxd" in filename:
            mxd = mapping.MapDocument(filename)
            for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(map, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
                if elm.text == "TEST 90666":
                    elm.text = "9067"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, the code now seems to run with no issues but the titles have not changed when I open the mxd files

Comment: You need to save the MXD after you make the changes to the text element.  mxd.save()

Comment: That's right, the changes should be saved. I have focused on the error you are receiving and have overlooked the saving operation.

Answer (score 0):

I have now made some changes to the code which it works but it is only updating 1 mxd file instead of all 3 I have in the folder. Any suggestions?

```
import arcpy, os
from os import listdir

mxdPath = r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Final Maps\New folder"

mxdFiles = [ f for f in listdir(mxdPath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(mxdPath,f)) and f[-3:] == 'mxd' ]

try:
    map = arcpy.mapping
    for mxdFile in mxdFiles:
        mxd = map.MapDocument(mxdPath + "\\" + mxdFile)
        for elm in map.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT"):
            if elm.text == "CountyProject130":
                elm.text = "Testing709"

     mxd.save()
     del mxd
     print "Complete!"
```

Comment: Please post a new question next time to get someone to provide an answer. For now, your problem is that you run `mxd.save()` outside of the `for` loop - indent the `mxd.save()` to the right one level.

Comment: Please ask another question

Comment: I will ask it in another question, I apologize and thanks everyone, indent did not work.